# Kentico 9 scheduled task not syncing media

Tags: kentico

I know there are upper limits on file size when it comes to media, but i'm testing with small images.

If i change a page, a simple content changed, the scheduled task syncs the change and i can see the update on the target server. If i upload an image to the media library, it doesn't sync via the scheduled tasks. I can sync it manually though.

I've read through the documentation, and didn't see anything where media files wouldn't sync, just the exact opposite though.

So what am i missing to get media files to sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's beacuse the scheduled task synchronizes only page changes. You cannot use the default Content synchronization task to synchronize other objects.

But you can use event handlers and some API to synchronize any type of staging task. 
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Automatically+synchronizing+staging+and+integration+tasks

Comment: Thanks Neshi. Would have been nice if this was built in. oh well.

Comment: No problem. Could be built in, but with setting which staging task types to sync. You can always post a new idea http://ideas.kentico.com

Comment: The reason only pages (data) are synced by the task is because web apps would require a rebuild. For that reason, the task doesn't sync files to prevent registered components being moved without the code actually being compiled.

I did a webinar earlier this year, focusing on setting up Advanced Content Staging. You can find out more about this concept, as well as some sample scheduled tasks to move all objects.

http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/technical-webinar-advanced-content-staging-scenarios

Comment: I'm working through your webinar Bryan. Thanks for the link.